# How to know Which character was replaced while using regex

Tags: java, regex

```
String string = "Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġs not cool \"oops" ;    
    string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", ... );
```

The problem is that I want to append to non alphanumeric non whitespace characters an escape character. i.e.

```
" -> \" 
' -> \'.
```

So what exactly should be a second argument in the `replaceAll` method ?
Or is there any other cool way (I don't want to hardcode)

Comment: Which particular flavour of regular expressions and under which programming language(s)?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Do you want to escape regex metacharacters? What exactly do you consider non-alphanumeric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is Java (I added the relevant tag), then you could do

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[\\W\\S]", "\\\\$0");
```

which will replace any non-alnum/non-space character with its escaped counterpart.

Note that the regex is making no attempt to detect whether a character is already escaped. You should also be aware that `\W` in Java is not locale-aware, so it will match Unicode letters, too.